# Big problem with wordpress pages, will not scroll in IE7

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, wordpress, scroll

Ok guys, this is re-visited, Ive rescued my website from the hackers and now its virus and malware free, thank you to all who pointed me in the right direction to fix it.

However my first problem still remains, the page in question is [http://www.whatcouldicook.com/wordpress](http://www.whatcouldicook.com)

Ive removed the extra quick search at the top including the RSS feeds div so that it validates in the W3C check but still no luck, every other browser works just fine.

Comment: You might want to state the question more clearly.

Comment: Your site scrolls fine for me in both IE 7 and IE 8.

Comment: I can verify the missing scrollbar in IE7 on XP.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolls okay for me in IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess since im on FF

try removing overflow:hidden on #main, maybe that will help

http://www.whatcouldicook.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/thematic/library/layouts/2c-r-fixed.css

Comment: i should add that it worked fine for me in firefox 3.0.11 and safari 4.